# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Razor Convert String to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-core, blazor

```
string[] dateFormats = new[] { "yyyy/MM/dd" };
//CultureInfo provider = newCultureInfo("en-US");
var dateFromJSON = configuration["returnToWorkDate"];
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateFromJSON, dateFormats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Visual Studio keeps complaining that it doesn't know what CultureInfo is.

I injected the

```
@inject Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration configuration
```

at the top of the page

and used Nuget to get the Microsoft.System.Globalization package.

Comment: How about `@using System.Globalization`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the fully-qualified type `System.Globalization.CultureInfo`:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateFromJSON, dateFormats, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Alternatively, add a [global using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-5.0#importing-shared-directives) for your views in `_ViewImports.cshtml`:

```
@using System.Globalization
```

Comment: Stange that it would do that. Thanks for the tip